# UITableView filtering

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, uitableview

I have to perform a search operation in tableview with searchbar.
Which have a label of a person's name and an image for these persons in its cell.

My code is

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    ArrPersons = ["Mahatma Gandhi","Pramukh Swami","Akshay Kumar","Sachin Tendulkar","Chetan Bhagat","Sardar Vallabhai Patel","Amitabh Bachchan"]
     arrPersonImages = ["1.png","2.png","3.png","4.png","5.png","6.png","7.png"]
}

func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    if (searchText.characters.count>0) {
        let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF CONTAINS[c] %@", searchText)
        ArrPersons = arrTemp
let array = (self.ArrPersons as NSArray).filteredArrayUsingPredicate(predicate)
    print(array)
        ArrPersons = array as! [String]

    }
    else
    {
        ArrPersons = arrTemp
    }
    self.tableviewww.reloadData()

}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
        {

            return self.ArrPersons.count
        }

   func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
    let cell = tableviewww.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("mycell")as! buildVcCell
   cell.personsImages.image = UIImage (named:arrPersonImages[indexPath.row] )
    cell.labelPersonNamess?.text = self.ArrPersons[indexPath.row]
    cell.addBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(BuildVc.AddbuttonClicked(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    return cell

}
```

The problem is this code only perform a search on the array of label persons. `arrPersonImages` is not filtering according to the name of the person entered it the searchbar.

Comment: you did not perform filter to the `arrPersonImages` in search textdidchange function, so all the images are still there. I think you'd better create a dictionary to keep the person name and image, like `[[name: "Michael", image: "1.png"], [name: "Peter", image: "2.png"], ...]`, then you just need to filter once for that array

Comment: thankyou @Enix for your suggestion..and i tried to change my code like this but its not working..

Comment: func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        if (searchText.characters.count>0) {
            let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF CONTAINS[c] %@", searchText)
            arrayyPersonsNImages = arrTemp
            let array = (self.arrayyPersonsNImages as NSMutableArray).filteredArrayUsingPredicate(predicate)
            print(array)
            arrayyPersonsNImages = array as AnyObject as! NSMutableArray
        }
        else
        {
            arrayyPersonsNImages = arrTemp
        }
        self.tableVieww.reloadData()

Comment: You can't filter the arrayyPersonsNImages array with previous defined `predicate`, since your predicate is defined with filtering the person name. You image name does not contain any person name, right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should create a "Model" for the Person (using [MVC](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MVC.html) pattern):

First, create "Person" Model:

```
struct Person {
    var name: String?
    var imageName: String?
}
```

instead of using two separated arrays for storing the persons's data, you can create an array of Person Model:

```
// add those vars to your ViewController:
var persons = [Person]()
var filteredPersons = [Person]()
var isFiltering = false

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    persons = [Person(name: "Ahmad", imageName: "img.png"), Person(name: "Harry", imageName: "img.png")]
}

func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        if (searchText.characters.count>0) {
            isFiltering = true
            filteredPersons = persons.filter {
                $0.name?.range(of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive, range: nil, locale: nil) != nil
            }
            print(filteredPersons)
        }
        else
        {
            isFiltering = false
            filteredPersons = persons
        }
        self.tableviewww.reloadData()
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return isFiltering == true ? filteredPersons.count : persons.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
     //...

     // getting the current person
     let currentPerson = isFiltering == true ? filteredPersons[indexPath.row] : persons[indexPath.row]

     // do the rest of the implementation...
     //...
}
```

**Note** that this is Swift 3 Code.

Answer (score 1):

I think it would make a lot of sense to combine the name and image for each character into a model-struct, and rather use this for the base of the cells. That being said, the following should help you on the way without altering your existing code too much. It will also shy away from actually changing your arrays...

A nice dynamic variable to make things a bit more automatic elsewhere:

```
var filteredPersons: [String] {
    return arrPersons.filter{ $0.contains(searchString) }
}
```

Which will give you

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return filteredPersons.count
}
```

Then in you cellForRowAtIndexPath function you can have the name and image created like this:

```
let name = filteredPersons[indexPath.row]
let imageIndex = arrPersons.index(of: name)
let image = UIImage(named: arrPersonImages[imageIndex])
```

Comment: Thankyou @T. Benjamin Larsen!! your answer was helpful for me. :)

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do searching is using an array with dictionary properties to keep the search result. Just for your reference:

```
class PersonController: UITableViewController {

    let ArrPersons = [["name": "Mahatma Gandhi", "image": "1.png"], ["name": "Akshay Kumar", "image": "2.png"]]
    var searchResult: [[String: String]]!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        searchResult = ArrPersons
    }

    func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        if (searchText.characters.count>0) {
            searchResult = arr.filter { (item) -> Bool in
                let name = item["name"]
                return name!.containsString(searchText)
            }
        }
        else
        {
            searchResult = ArrPersons
        }
        self.tableView.reloadData()

    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
        return self.searchResult.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("mycell")as! buildVcCell
        let person = searchResult[indexPath.row]
        cell.personsImages.image = UIImage(named: person["image"])  // Person image
        cell.labelPersonNamess?.text = person["name"]  // Person name
        cell.addBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(BuildVc.AddbuttonClicked(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: thankyou so much..it really helped me and now its working! :)

Comment: i have a array containing dictionary as elements like this - (
        {
        images = "1.png";
        names = "Mahatma Gandhi";
    },
        {
        images = "2.png";
        names = "Pramukh Swami";
    },
        {
        images = "4.png";
        names = "Sachin Tendulkar";
    }
      
)
is it possible to perform the same search operation on it?

Comment: Sure. but remember to change to key name of the dictionary where you reference it in your code. e.g., `person["images"]`, `person["names"]`, `item["names"]`