# Change tableview cell index

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, cell, indexpath

I'm building an app that pulls data from internet (events) then it displays all the events in a tableview (different sections based on dates). 
If user clicks on any event it expands, and then they can favourite the event or event host. How i can reorder my table to show those favourited events first. Because i didn't build my app with any in app "data model", what i mean is that all the data displayed in the tableview (ordering) is based on the pull request, what ever comes first is displayed first.

Are there any way to force some certain cells to top of the section? Manually reorder the cell's in code in my situation?

And one other question? I'm using section headers (dates) , but can i have two headers so it's (Header)date - (subheader)city - (cell)event. Or am i limited to only one section header?

Comment: You need to store the "favourite" data somewhere. Use that to reorder your array content.

Comment: Create a *data model*. Order the model and reload the tableView.

Comment: I think [this question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39738518/uitableview-filtering/39740482#39740482) should be -hopefully- useful to your case.

Comment: Obviously you need to somehow put favourite events on beginning of datasource array. Creating of model is the best way to do it.